# What is the pi'al form in Hebrew?

Tags: hebrew, conjugation

I have seen scattered references to a pi'al conjugation, which I understand to be similar to, but distinct from, pi'el.

For example, for ק-ד-ש, I have seen **קִדַּשׁ** and **קִדֵּשׁ**. My impression is, **קִדַּשׁ** is used in the Bible, while **קִדֵּשׁ** is used in modern Hebrew. That is touched on in this comment [here](https://www.booksataglance.com/book-reviews/review-of-beginning-biblical-hebrew-a-grammar-and-illustrated-reader-by-john-cook-and-robert-holmstedt/#:~:text=they%20consistently%20list%20the%20D%2Dstem%20as%20Piel%20verbs%2C%20even%20though%20roughly%20half%20of%20these%20follow%20a%20Pial%20pattern%20(e.g.%2C%20it%20is%20uniformly%20%D7%A7%D6%B4%D7%93%D6%BC%D6%B7%D7%A9%D7%81%20in%20the%20Tanak%2C%20but%20BBH%20lists%20%D7%A7%D6%B4%D7%93%D6%BC%D6%B5%D7%A9%D7%81%20to%20memorize)).

Is there a difference between pi'el and pi'al? When is pi'al used instead of pi'el?

Comment: There's exactly one instance of קִדַּשׁ in the Bible (1 Kings 8:64), so that book review is at least overstating its case.

Comment: The Biblical Hebrew piel has both forms without distinction in meaning. I haven’t seen “pial” used anywhere. It can be confusing that in all forms except 3m.sg the tsere changes to schwa or patach, so maybe somebody suggested “pial” so that only the 3m.sg with tsere would be “irregular”? See https://uhg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/stem_piel.html#paradigm for the forms. Be aware that the review is written by a master’s student; their critique on memorizing קוּם is also a bit odd.

Comment: Thank you @Keelan. Reviewing the few google hits for "pial", I now understand that it is just being used as a description of an irregular form of "piel". So I withdraw my question.